# php txt files update

Tags: php, html

Trying to update/edit txt files using php. I keep getting error undefined array.

Here's the code for update.php

```
<?php
$term = $_GET['term'];
$myfile = fopen("Files/$term", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$data = fread($myfile, filesize("Files/$term"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Update</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="save.php" name="Form">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <tr><label for="name">Content</label></tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="term" type="text" step="any" name="term" required><?php echo $data; ?></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit">Update</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is save.php

```
<?php
$data = $_GET['data'];

$myfile = fopen("$data", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $data);
fclose($myfile);
header('location: index.php');
?>
```

In update.php, I define the file names to $term. Then I wanted the new updated data to be called $data and send it to save.php however I keep getting undefined array error. I'm still a student learning php, I hope someone can fix my coding.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: `$data = $_POST['term'];` in `save.php`

Comment: WHy are you using `$data` as both the filename and the contents to write to it?

Comment: _Warning_! your code allows writing to an arbitrary file on the server - with this code an attacker can inject any kind of data or script to your system.

Comment: Please let us know which exact line is causing the error, and what the exact error message is.

Comment: @Barmar you solution will only create a new file not update the existing one

Comment: @kmoser Line 2 in save.php

Comment: If the file already exists it will overwrite it.

Comment: It's not my code, it's your code. I just showed how to get the parameter from the form correctly. Since you're using `method="post"` you have to use `$_POST`, not `$_GET`. And the textarea has `name="term"`, not `name="data"`.

Comment: Ok so how do I modified the code to update the existing file? It's meant to overwrite the file not just append.

Comment: That's what it does. `w` mode overwrites, `a` mode appends.